# MySQL UPDATE statement performance

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

On a table with over 10 million rows, which one of these `UPDATE` statements likely to faster, or are they much of a muchness?

1. `UPDATE table SET col1 = col2 WHERE col1 IS NULL;`
2. `UPDATE table SET col1 = col2 WHERE col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL;`

Neither `col1` nor `col2` are keys or indexed. They are actually `datetime` fields, if that changes anything.

---

Note: I'm fairly sure that the queries achieve the same result:

Query 1. will update `col1` every time, including setting it to `NULL` if `col2 is NULL`.

Query 2. will update `col1` only if `col2` has a value, thereby leaving `col1` as `NULL` if `col2 is NULL`.

They both change the data in the same way. One **sets** `col1` to `NULL` when `col2 is NULL`, the other **leaves** `col1` as `NULL` when `col2 is NULL`, but in all cases `col1` was `NULL` to begin with.

Comment: two query are different. Both query will not update same rows.

Comment: As @SureshKamrushi says, they are not the same, logically - but also observation says that the 1st would be faster as it is performing less checks - though the *actual* performance difference may well be negligible.  Have you tried profiling them?

Comment: You should also take into account how many of the 10 Million have col2 as NULL. If you only have 5 that have col2 as not null, then the second one should be faster as it has not to do almost 10 Million updates.

Comment: Analyzing this query, maybe the performance will depends on the content of the table. If you have many `NULL` in `col1` and less `col2` with values, there are less to update. Meaning, `col1` and `col1` values is inversely proportional with respect to performance.

Comment: Also depends on the keys. are there keys?

Comment: I have now added info about keys to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to the various comments & answers about measuring rather than guessing, and also to the comments regarding the count of rows where `col2 is NULL` vs `col2` having a value of some kind, I ran 4 tests on a test table:

```
                            | Query 1          | Query 2
 col2 almost all NULL       |  5 min 27.96 sec |  4 min 20.38 sec
 col2 almost all has values | 34 min 31.64 sec | 32 min 31.54 sec
```

Conclusion:
**Query 2 is marginally faster in both cases**.

Answer (score 1):

Performance is better measured than guessed. Yet here is my guess:
It heavily depends on your usage of **indeces**, and their **cardinality**.

That means: if col2 has an index with thousands of different values and null beeing one of them, it´ll be faster than query 1. If there is no query and col2 almost always is null, it will be slower.

*Best performance will be achieved if you have a two-column-index spanning both cols, and use both cols in the where-part*.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on different factors.

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = col2;
```

Will do a full table scan and modification in any case.

These queries

```
UPDATE table SET col1 = col2 WHERE col1 IS NULL;
UPDATE table SET col1 = col2 WHERE col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL;
```

will result in faster operation, if col1 and col2 are indexed.

You can get information about what is done in which case if you execute

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE table SET col1 = col2;
EXPLAIN UPDATE table SET col1 = col2 WHERE col1 IS NULL;
EXPLAIN UPDATE table SET col1 = col2 WHERE col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Just tried this. Turns out `MySQL` doesn't let you use `EXPLAIN` with `UPDATE` statements I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the second format is usually preferable, but of course it will depend on your data. It is important to note that indexes on the columns in question may not include null values, depending on the database provider and the way that the indexes are defined. Even if indexes are defined, they may not improve performance, and depending on your statistics they may not be used at all.